# Angular UI Router Same TemplateUrls issue for different States

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, mean-stack

I am using AngularJS with $stateProvider with 2 different states pointing to same templateurls. Code Snippet is below

```
$stateProvider
.state('training', {
        url: "/training",
        templateUrl: "partials/training.html",
        controller: function($scope, $http, $state, $uibModal){
            console.log("Main Training State");
            $http.get('/api/training').success(function (response){
                var data = response;
                $scope.courses=data.courses;
            }).error(function(err,status){
                console.log(err);
            });
            $scope.openReadMoreModal = function (course) {
                var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
                    animation: true,
                    templateUrl: 'readmoremodal.html',
                    controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl',
                    resolve: {
                      modalObject: course
                    }
                });
            };
        }
    })
    .state('mytraining', {
        url: "training/me",
        templateUrl: "partials/training.html",
        controller: function($scope, $http, $state, $uibModal){
            console.log("get My Events in the training html");
            $http.get('/api/training/myevents').success(function (response){
                console.log("response :"+ response);
                $scope.courses = response.courses;
            }).error(function(err,status){
                console.log(err);
            });
            $scope.openReadMoreModal = function (course) {
                var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
                    animation: true,
                    templateUrl: 'readmoremodal.html',
                    controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl',
                    resolve: {
                      modalObject: course
                    }
                });
            };
        }
    })
```

Issue is that control doesn't flow to the mytraining state. Please tell me what is the issue?

Comment: should not the url be: url: "/training/me", for mytraining state

Comment: @RahulArora Thanks.. You saved my day. It works..

Comment: I will write it as an answer. If you can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be:

```
url: "/training/me",
```

and **NOT**

```
url: "training/me",
```

in mytraining state

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
.state('training', {
    url: "/training",
    templateUrl: "partials/training.html",

/* ... some config ... */

.state('training.me', {
        url: "/me",
        templateUrl: "partials/training.html",
```